# Page goes blank when echoing a session variable from a php file

Tags: php, html, session

There are two files, index.php and file.php. I set a session variable in file.php to 1. Then I check in index.php if this session variable is set to 1. If it is, it is supposed to echo that variable. But instead, my browser goes blank. It looks like all the html code vanishes as seen in the developer tools of the browser (no html content). If I comment out that and instead try to echo a string satisfying the if condition, then the page appears but does not echo the string.

file.php

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<html>
<head>
  <title>Password test, page 2</title>
<head>
<body>
  .
  .
  .
 <?php
  if($name === $good_name && $pass === $good_pass){
        echo "That is the correct log-in information";
     }else{
        $_SESSION["flag"] = 1; // setting the variable in file.php
        header('Location: index.php'); exit(); //directing to that file
     } 
  ?>    
</body>
</html>
```

index.php

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     .
     .
     .
<?php
if ($_SESSION["flag"] === 1)
    {echo "invalid";  //this doesn't output the string
    echo . $_SESSION["flag"]; //this gives me blank page
}
?>
```

Is my code syntactically wrong or if the logic is incorrect? Please point it out.

**EDIT#1** file.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Password test, page 2</title>
  <head>


  <body>
      <?php 
         $name  = $_POST['username'];
         $pass  = $_POST['password']; 

       //read the contents of our password file.
         $myFile = "pass/password.txt";
         $fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
         $data = fgets($fh);
         fclose($fh);
         $data1 = trim($data);

         //split the text into an array
         $text = explode(":",$data1);

         //assign the data to variables
         $good_name = $text[0];
         $good_pass = $text[1];

         //compare the strings
         if($name === $good_name && $pass === $good_pass){
            echo "That is the correct log-in information";
         }else{
            $_SESSION["flag"] = 1;
            header('Location: index.php'); exit();
         } 
      ?>    
        <br> 

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: well file.php  is missing the second open php tag `<?php` just before the if statement

Comment: It looks like else part in file.php has never been hit

Comment: sorry it is in the original code. forgot to paste here in the snippet

Comment: None of these variables have values `$name === $good_name && $pass === $good_pas`  no assignments,  `$name = something`  `===` also check the type, sure you want that instead of `==`

Comment: @SaravananSampathkumar It did before because if i put another uri instead of index.php it redirects me to there.

Comment: No, I mean to say, else part of your file.php never gets executed. Because of which your session variable isn't set

Comment: This is invalid `echo . $_SESSION` that dot echo `.`  also `$_SESSION["flag"] === 1)` will fail if `1` is a string `'1'` because of `===` instead of `==`

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix those variables work alright originally. they have been defined in the code. i thought them not relevant to show the entire definition of these here. Should I? Can they be the problem. However before introducing session variables, everything worked fine.

Comment: error message are going some where. Look into enabling error being displayed You should be able to add `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);` to the top of your script or add to php.ini, ` error_reporting  =  E_ALL | E_STRICT `

Comment: do the var_dump on $_SESSION["flag"] in index.php before your condition and try '==' instead of '==='

Comment: Can you update your full file.php file?

Comment: This is defiantly wrong `echo . $_SESSION`, that said I would add this to the top of the first php script ( after the open php tag )  `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(-1);` turn on error reporting.  However error reporting {likely} wont catch syntax error if they happen in the same file.

Comment: <?php
 if (isset($_SESSION['flag']) && $_SESSION["flag"] === 1)
 {
  echo $_SESSION['flag'];
 }
 ?>

Comment: Replace that on index.php file and check

Comment: @justrohu Doing var_dump gives me NULL. This means, variable has never been set? Why is that.

Comment: @AkritiAnand { $_SESSSION } check the spelling, its $_SESSION and not $_SESSSION, please correct and do the var_dump again

Comment: @justrohu I'm sorry for that typo. But the error remains.

Comment: try if($_SESSION["flag"] == 1) in your index.php instead of if($_SESSION["flag"] === 1)

Comment: @SaravananSampathkumar After doing what you said, i'm getting this at the botton of my page (otherwise everything appears) *int(1) 1*

Comment: @SaravananSampathkumar It works now! Thank you so much. Can you tell me where i was going wrong and what did you correct?

Comment: Just like @ArtisticPhoenix pointed, you had mistake by adding "." before the $_SESSION variable. Also, you haven't checked whether the session has been set or not.